# Multiple sliders onMouseOut event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have one jQuery slider. When I click on the textbox, the slider div will show. Here is my html code:

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="JavaScript:getLiveTraffic()">Live Traffic Condition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here is the dynamically created html components which were created when the menu item is selected:

```
function getLiveTraffic() {

var htmlStr = "<table style='width:100%;font-size:12px;text-align:center;height:90px;'>";
htmlStr += "<tr><td><input id='timeI' style='width:100px;' onClick='getStartTime();' placeholder='Start Time'></input></td><td><input id='timeII' style='width:100px;' onClick='getEndTime();' placeholder='End Time'></input></td></tr>";

htmlStr += "<tr><td><div style='display:none;width:120px;padding:5px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background: linear-gradient(white, #F2F2F2);' id='timePicker'>";
htmlStr += "<div style='width:120px;margin-bottom:8px;' id='hour'></div>";
htmlStr += "<div style='width:120px;' id='min'></div>"; 
htmlStr += "<span id='hourd'>0:</span><span id='mind'>00</span>";
htmlStr += "</div></td>";

document.getElementById("divGetLiveTraffic").innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

My JavaScript to call the getStartTime():

```
function getStartTime()
{
    $("#hour").slider({max: 23});
        $("#hour").on("slide", function(event, ui)
        {
            document.getElementById("hourd").innerHTML = ui.value + ":";
            ;
        });
        $("#min").slider({max: 59});
        $("#min").on("slide", function(event, ui)
        {
            document.getElementById("mind").innerHTML = ui.value + "";
            ;
        });
        $("#timeI").click(function(evt) {
            $("#timePicker").show();
        });

}
```

Then span class below the slider changes the value when it slides. However, I'm not sure how to **set the value into the textbox input**.

Also, when finish choosing the time by sliding the slider, the time id is supposed to hide. I not sure how to **perform onMouseOut event as well cause there is two sliders**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not HTML code.  Can you give a fiddle?

Comment: I am creating the html component dynamically as the second part of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you actually try to achieve.
I would like to post an answer for your two questions.

To set the value into the textbox input, you can go like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="time1">
```

JavaScrit(jQuery):

```
$("#time1").val("new value");
```

The document of `.val()` is here : http://api.jquery.com/val/

---

And to do something when mouse is out of a div:

HTML:

```
<div id="myarea">
   myarea
</div>
```

JavaScrit(jQuery):

```
$( "#myarea" ).mouseout(function() {
  // now mouse is out of 'myarea'
});
```

The document of `.mouseout()` is here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I got two sliders inside a div. So when I switvh from first to second slider, it execute the onMouseOut event. Is there any possible way to do it in this way: I finish sliding both sliders, then fire the onMouseOut event

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$("#divGetLiveTraffic").on("click", "timeI", function(){
  $(this).val($("#hourd").text() + $("#mind").text());
});

$("divGetLiveTraffic").on("mouseout", "timeI", function(){
  //.........
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both does not work. The textbox input keep showing 0:00 although I slide it and the onMouseOut does not work as well.

Comment: I have updated the answer, and i think what you need is to use javascript [bubbling](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing), and **jquery's** on api, hope that will help you!

Comment: Sure thanks for the effort. I'd figured out the way to solve it. Thanks a lot!